# WHERE columnName IS NULL but Not Getting Expected Result

Tags: mysql, null, where-clause, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am only starting my first project for my portfolio and I am *completely* bamboozled...

During my EDA, I noticed the **continents** column with NULL values are good for queries specifically about continents as the corresponding population column has the total figure of the population, regardless of the date.

So I want to look at countries **only** (location column) by filtering out the NULL values in the continent column:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    covidDeaths
WHERE continent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    date asc;
```

However, when I do this, the NULL values still show up in the result table.

[image: However, when I do this, the NULL values still show up in the result table.]

Comment: Are you sure they're `NULL`, not empty strings? Try `WHERE continent != ''`

Comment: Wow I feel silly lol - Thank you! It was right under my nose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that those values are not NULL but they are empty strings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).